# Assign a Function Key to reliably switch to another running app

Tags: windows-xp, automation, function-keys, alt-tab

I have a pc till in my shop.  I want to run another app on the till.  I would like to be able to assign a Function key (eg F2) to switch that running instance to the front (over the till software which takes up the whole screen (no start menu shown).

What is the best way of doing this?

Are there any apps that I can use to assign an app to a Key?

Is there an AutoHotKey script for this?

For extra points the app could be started when the key is pressed if its not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite an answer to my question, but in the end I just got the staff in the shop to hit the  Windows key when they wanted to switch.  This brings up the start bar over the till interface and they can click on the app they want to view.

It aint pretty but it works.

Comment: It's [fairly trivial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Activate) to write an Autohotkey script that does this. With an tiny extra bit of work, it's even possible for match by partial program title, process ID, etc. It looks like you've found an alternative workaround, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely start up the app with a hotkey.  I don't have XP in front of me, but normally when you right click on a shortcut (in the start menu or desktop) and select the properties menu, then there should be a space for a shortcut key (you select the blank and actually do the key combination to fill it in).

I couldn't get it to switch to the program when I tried it, so it might start another instance of it instead.

Comment: Thanks, but its the switching I'm more interested in.